# A way to filter a distinct set of columns using a measure from the same table - Tabular2017

Tags: dax, ssas-tabular, distinct-values

[Overview of the table in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LR3Bj.png)

I need to get a distinct count of the column Fkey_Dim_Resource_ID that has holiday to spare.

My Table consists of five columns:

- Resource_Allocated_Holiday_ID (Primary Key)
- Fkey_Dim_Resource_ID
- Fkey_Dim_HolidayYear_ID
- Fkey_Dim_Company_ID
- Allocated_Holiday_Hrs_Qty

Measure:

```
Allocated Holiday (Hrs):=  Var X= SUM([Allocated_Holiday_Hrs_Qty])
Return if(X =0; BLANK();X)
```

This measure below then uses the above, and the holiday spent from another metric:

```
Remaining Holiday (Hrs):= Var X = 'HolidayEntry Numbers'[Allocated Holiday (Hrs)] - [#Holiday Hours]
Return if(X=0;BLANK();X)
```

And now, I would like a metric that gives me the `distinct count` of `Fkey_Dim_ResourceID where 'Remaining Holiday (hrs)' >0`.

I have tried a lot of different stuff, but cannot seem to get it right.

```
test:= 
ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE('HolidayEntry Numbers'
                ;'HolidayEntry Numbers'[Fkey_Dim_Company_ID]
                ;'HolidayEntry Numbers'[Fkey_Dim_Resource_ID];
                'HolidayEntry Numbers'[Fkey_Dim_HolidayYear_Id]
            )
 ;"RemainingHoliday"; sum( [Remaining Holiday (Hrs)])
 )
```

I would like for a distinct count of Fkey_Dim_Resource_ID that has holiday left, that takes into account the context.
Thanks in advance.

With this measure:

```
 test4 virker når ressourcen er med:=COUNTROWS (
          FILTER (
                    ADDCOLUMNS (
                                VALUES ( 'HolidayEntry 
   Numbers'[Fkey_Dim_Resource_ID]);

                                "remholiday"; CALCULATE ( [Remaining Holiday 
    (Hrs)] )
                               );
                    [remholiday] > 0
                )
    )
```

I get the following result:

[Result of the advice1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRltY.png)

So the metric works, when in the context of a Resource, but not when in the context of a Fkey_dim_holiday_Year_ID.

Thanks ion advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
Resources with remaining holiday hours =
COUNTROWS (                           // counts rows in a table
    FILTER (                          // returns a table, filtering based on predicate
        // below is unique values of the column in context, as a
        // one-column table
        VALUES ( 'HolidayEntry Numbers'[Fkey_Dim_Resource_ID] ),
        [Remaining Holiday (hrs)] > 0 // keep rows meeting this criterion
    )
)
```

As a matter of style, you should fully qualify column names as `'Table'[Column]`, and never fully qualify measure references, i.e. don't prefix with table name. This conforms with all style guides I know, and helps to ensure your code is unambiguous (since both columns and measures are referenced in square brackets).

Comment: Many thanks for the input. But I have tried that one myself. If you use the metric in the context of the related dimension it does not work. F.ex Fkey_Dim_Holiday_Year_ID. That way oof doing it only works, when being in the context of a Fkey_Dim_Resource_ID.

Comment: Right now I am experimenting with something like this, but I can not get to access the columns in the Var Table.  test5 sumx:=
Var T= Filter(CALCULATETABLE(
     ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS('HolidayEntry Numbers'[Fkey_Dim_Company_ID];'HolidayEntry Numbers'[Fkey_Dim_HolidayYear_Id];'HolidayEntry Numbers'[Fkey_Dim_Resource_ID]);
       "RemHoliday";            CALCULATE([Remaining Holiday (Hrs)] )
       )
       
    );   [RemHoliday]>0)

return CALCULATE( COUNTROWS(   VALUES(T)))

Comment: If I could do a distinct count on the Fkey_Dim_Resource_ID on the Variable Table T, it might be working. But Visual Studio will not let me do it.

Comment: Please enhance your question with example tables and a mock-up of expected output. As you have described it, I see no reason that the code I posted shouldn't work. Obviously this means I'm misunderstanding your intent.

Comment: How to add screenshots to this platform?